# A multi-argument function in C in which the second argument is never used

Tags: c, gcc

I have two functions:

```
int hash64(int key0, int key1);
int hash32(int key0, int UNUSED_ARG);
```

and a structure with a function pointer

```
int (*hash)(int key0, int key1);
```

So, `hash32` only uses `key0`, but I need to declare it this way in order to assign it to the function pointer. But obviously GCC complains a lot when I do this. If it's a single-argument function, we can do

```
int hash1(int key);
int hash2(void);
```

or whatever, but apparently int `hash32(int key0, void)` isn't valid syntax according to GCC. So, what's the correct way to declare hash32?

Comment: `(void)` doesn't designate the argument is unused! It designates the function accepts no arguments.

Comment: *"But obviously GCC complains a lot when I do this"*. Actually, it would help if you told us what the error is you are getting.. I'm guessing an unused argument warning, but I can't simulate that locally.  Please show the compiler output of the error.

Comment: Which specific compiler warnings are you worried about?  It is easy enough to quell the unused argument warning — add `(void)UNUSED_ARG;` to the function body.

Comment: I think he's compiling with `-Wunused-parameter`. That would explain the error.

Comment: Yes. It compiles, but it complains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always define your function matching the pointer type with which you want to use your function.

If GCC complains about an unused parameter you can just silence it with

```
int hash1(int key0, int key1)
{
  (void)key1;
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The declaration looks like this

```
int hash32(int key0, int dummy);
```

and in the function definition

```
int hash32(int key0, int dummy)
{
    //... rest of code
    (void) dummy;  // to avoid warnings for unused parameters.
    //.. return as required
}
```