# invalid cast from 'GtkButton' to 'GtkEntry'

Tags: css, c, gtk3

I wrote a code in `GTK3` and works fine:
[image]

As long as I don't use the compiler FLAGS `-Wall -Wextra`.
But when I turn them ON, I get:

```
invalid cast from 'GtkButton' to 'GtkEntry'
```

And I can't figure out where the problem is.This happens After the User type something and hits the Button.

Here is the Code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void btn_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
        g_print("%s\n", gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(data)));
        gtk_editable_select_region(GTK_EDITABLE(data), 0,-1);
        gtk_editable_copy_clipboard(GTK_EDITABLE(data));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window, *grid;
    GtkWidget *label, *label_fn;
    GtkWidget *fn_entry;
    GtkWidget *button;

            //---------- CSS -------------
    GtkCssProvider *provider;
    GdkDisplay *display;
    GdkScreen *screen;
    //---------------------------

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "MyApp");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 370, 155);
    gtk_window_set_resizable (GTK_WINDOW(window), TRUE);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 5);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    /*     Create a Grid     */
    grid = gtk_grid_new();
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER (grid), 15);
    gtk_widget_set_name(grid, "myGrid");
    gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 5);
    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(grid), 5);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), grid);

    /*     Create first Label     */
    label = gtk_label_new("Please enter your Information:");
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top(label, 25);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start(label, 85);

    /*     Create second Label     */
    label_fn = gtk_label_new("First Name: ");
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start(label_fn, 10);

    /*     Create an Entry:     */
    fn_entry = gtk_entry_new();

    /*     Create a Button    */
    button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_Write text");
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(btn_clicked), fn_entry);
    g_signal_connect(fn_entry, "activate", G_CALLBACK(btn_clicked), fn_entry);


    /*     Putting all together      */
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), label,      0, 0, 2, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), label_fn,   0, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), fn_entry,   1, 1, 1, 1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button,     1, 2, 1, 1);

        // ---------------------------------------------------- CSS -----------------------------------------------------------
    provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
    display = gdk_display_get_default ();
    screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

    const gchar *myCssFile = "mystyle.css";
    GError *error = 0;

    gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(provider, g_file_new_for_path(myCssFile), &error);
    g_object_unref (provider);
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

mystyle.css:

```
GtkWindow {
    background-color: magenta;
    color: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: blue;
}

#myGrid {
    background-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-color: grey;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc myApp.c -o myApp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 `
```

works fine.

But the function `static void btn_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)` has two parameters and used is only `gpointer data`.

If I use `-Wall -Wextra` I get:

```
myApp.c: In function ‘btn_clicked’:
myApp.c:3:36: warning: unused parameter ‘widget’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 static void btn_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
                                    ^
```

And here starts the problem.

When I remove the parameter `GtkWidget *widget` and compile it (which compiles fine), after I run it and I type something in that field and I click on that Button (Write text) I get the following:

```
(myApp:5778): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GtkButton' to 'GtkEntry'

(myApp:5778): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed
(null)

(myApp:5778): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GtkButton' to 'GtkEditable'

(myApp:5778): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_editable_select_region: assertion 'GTK_IS_EDITABLE (editable)' failed

(myApp:5778): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GtkButton' to 'GtkEditable'

(myApp:5778): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_editable_copy_clipboard: assertion 'GTK_IS_EDITABLE (editable)' failed
```

So, my Question is how to fix that?

Comment: I use the following a lot to shut up the compiler with unused variables in GTK3. `__attribute__((unused))`, place that immediately after the variable in the function declaration. Here is one I used: `void adjust_fan (GtkWidget *wid __attribute__((unused)), gpointer ptr)`.  Then I can use `gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wfatal-errors` without any complaints.  You are not required to add it to the function prototypes though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First the general rule:**

You mustn't change the signature of your callback functions!
If it is defined to have 2 paramters then you **never ever** drop one paramter!

If you do not use one of these parameters, you can just [silence your compiler warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378893/a-multi-argument-function-in-c-in-which-the-second-argument-is-never-used/41378986#41378986).

```
(void)widget;
```

What you do is using a `GtkWidget*` holding the address of the widget and treat it as if it was your user data pointer.

To make it more obvious what happens when you do this:
GTK calls your callback function:

```
button->event_cb(button, userdata);
```

But your function does not match the signature:

```
my_button_cb(void* mydata)
{
  // here mydata holds the value from argument button.
  // The value from argument userdata is lost!
}
```

You mention that it compiles fine. This is no surprise. When you call `g_signal_connect` to add your callback, the type of the function pointer is not preserved. The compiler does not know how the signature should look like and is not able to throw an error message at you.
This does not mean that your code is correct.

**Additional note:**

As ptomato pointed out, it is possible to drop parameters at the end of the list. While this is technically possibly I would not encourage to use this way. Especially if you are providing the callback function yourself. I would regard this to be bad practice.

Things are a bit different if you want to use a callback function that is provided by some library. There it could happen that the signature does not exactly match and you would need to write a wrapper to make parameters match.
In this case I don't see an urgent need to add this wrapper just to have cleaner code.
After browsing some GTK samples I even found a way to use a callback where the order of the parameters is not matching: `g_signal_connect_swapped`. With this function the parameters are provided in different order to the callback. This would allow to use library functions like `gtk_widget_destroy()` to signals that provide the window only as userdata in second parameter.

But again: If you provide the callback yourselfe, I wouldn't use such tricks.

Comment: I already explained the first part of your Answer. And I definitely do not want to silence the compiler warning. I need to change that function some how that works when I click that Button.

Comment: You explained that you removed that first parameter which is the root cause of your problem. The signature of the function is defined by GTK+3. As a user of this interface you are not in the position to change it. The interface definition from GTK is "the law" and you have to stick to it. Use the parameter or silence the warning. There are no other options.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but I'm happy for the moment with that.

Comment: It's not quite true that you can't change the function signature. You can drop parameters off the end if you don't use them. You just can't remove parameters from the beginning or the middle, like `widget`. For detailed explanation, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402597/why-does-gobject-method-still-get-called-even-if-callback-arguments-dont-match/22419961#22419961).

Comment: `G_GNUC_UNUSED` is another way to silence the warning, by the way.